# How do I get HTML-linked JS files to use Require?

Tags: node.js, express

I am an express newbie, and I am trying to get a static HTML page to read details from a file in Express.

Initially I had a static HTML page where users could register where they were based on a particular day (as we are now rather flexible with working arrangements). However, it became apparent that I needed to store the current situation somewhere each time someone updated their details (and retrieve it when someone else signs on), so I did some investigating and came up with Node and Express.

I have an HTML file in the public directory, and it links to a JS file where I want to do a "fs" read.

app.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var steveRouter = require('./routes/steve');
app.use('/steve', steveRouter);
```

routes/steve.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../public', 'steve.html'))
});

module.exports = router;
```

public/steve.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Hello World : title</title>
    <script src="steve.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="loadUp()">
        <h3>small-ish heading</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

public/steveHtml.js

```
const fs = require('fs');

function loadUp() {
    alert("Ciao");
    let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('student.json');
    let student = JSON.parse(rawdata);
    console.log(student);
    alert(student.name);
}
```

The server starts ok, but the browser shows the message "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at steveHtml.js:1"

This is probably the wrong way of doing it, but I would love to know :

1. how do I get the "called" JS file to recognise the require command?
2. is there a better/simpler/easier way of accomplishing what I want?

Comment: This is not how things work.  Server-side code runs in nodejs and uses `require()` to load other files.  Code that runs in your HTML pages runs in the browser and must follow the rules of browser Javascript, not nodejs Javascript and does not use `require()`.    So, client-side code is different than server-side code and each has different environments to run in and different things they can do.  You don't run nodejs code inside the browser/web page.  As an example, you don't use the nodejs `fs` module in web page Javascript.  The browser does not offer that capability.

Comment: If you describe what you're actually trying to accomplish in the web page (using words), then perhaps we could help explain how to do that.

Comment: It seems like you want to store some data client-side? as in you don't want to store it in a database, just in the browser? if yes there's a pretty simple solution. Also, is the data you want to store sensitive?

Comment: I need to put it on a machine which a lot of people can use, so server-side is probably the best option.The data is definitely not sensitive.